# How can I get data from a sharepoint 2010 server from a separate asp.net web application?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, development, asp.net

We have a SharePoint 2010 server with data in lists. We also built an asp.net application which sits on a separate non-sharepoint server. Is there a way I could get the data from the sharepoint web application from my asp.net app without installing sharepoint foundation on the asp.net server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Is there a way I could get the data from the SharePoint web application from my asp.net app without installing SharePoint foundation on the asp.net server?**

Yes, you can read data from SharePoint in your ASP.NET Using SharePoint CSOM.

`Client-Side Object Model (CSOM)` is mainly used to build client applications and enable us to access SharePoint Sites that are hosted outside without using web services.

**What do you need in order to use CSOM?**

You just needed to add the below assemblies as a reference to your solution to be able to work with the Client Object Model.

- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll

These assemblies can be found in the 14 Hive folder: `%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\ISAPI.` So you should copy it first from your SharePoint Server to your solution folder then add it as a reference in your solution.

For Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code check

- [Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx)
- [SharePoint Client Object Modal (CSOM)](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-client-object-modal-csom/)
- [SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model: Introduction](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/399156/sharepoint-client-object-model-introduction)

Also, you can Accessing SharePoint 2010 Lists by Using `REST-based web services` for more details/ examples check this MSDN article [Accessing SharePoint 2010 Lists by Using WCF Data Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134614(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I Didnt know i could copy the dlls